# Error: Call to a possibly undefined method crearNotaS through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new at programming and I'm working on a 'minigame' for my career.

I'm getting this error, hope someone can help me out.

```
    public class Notas
{
    public var stage:Stage;
    public var velocidad:int =  5;

    public var i:int = 0;
    public var notaS:Array = new Array(16);
    public var notaD:Array = new Array(16);

    public function Notas(escenario:Stage)
    {
        stage = escenario;
    }

    public function Inicializar():void
    {
        crearNotaS(0xFFFFFF, 30, 10, 0, 0);
    }

    public function Destruir():void
    {
        if (notaS[i].y < 720)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < notaS.length; i++)
            {
                stage.removeChild(notaS[i])
            }
        }
    }

    public function Mover():void
    {
        notaS[i].y += velocidad;
    }

    public function drawRect(color:uint, ancho:int, alto:int, x:int, y:int):Sprite
    {
        var dj:Sprite = new Sprite();

        dj.graphics.beginFill(color,1);
        dj.graphics.drawRect(0,0,ancho,alto);
        dj.graphics.endFill();

        dj.x = x;
        dj.y = y;

        return(dj);
    }

    public function asignarNotas():void
    {
        notaS[0] = 1
    }

    public function crearNotaS(color:int, ancho:int, alto:int, x:int, y:int):void
    {
        var contador:int = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < notaS.length; i++)
        {
            if (notaS[i] == 1 && i == 0)
            {
                notaS[i] = drawRect(color, ancho, alto, x, y);
                stage.addChild(notaS[i]);
                notaS[i].y = -alto / 2;
            }

            else if (notaS[i] == 1 && i > 0)
            {
                for (j = i; j < notaS.length; j++)
                {
                    contador = i - j

                    notaS[i] = drawRect(color, ancho, alto, x, notaS[j].y + alto * contador);
                    stage.addChild(notaS[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its supposed to create a array of squares (only if the content of the index is a 1, if it is a 0 then it won't create the square there.) one on top of each other and then move them all down, like a guitar hero.

Probably the way im doing it isn't proper but well, its the 1st thing i'm doing on my own...

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript is an object oriented Language. Classes are supposed to be objects too and when you want to access their methods you either need to make an instance of them first or make sure the target function is of type "Static", which has limitations of its own.
This is all about core concepts which you need to know before running your code. I suggest taking a look at some tutorials about classes. This might be a good start:
[Tutorial: Understanding Classes in AS3 Part 1](http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2009/08/25/tutorial-understanding-classes-in-as3-part-1/)

But about your code. It misses some imports and variable definitions, not a major flaw though. Im able to run your code. I will attach a zip file containing the AS3 AIR project which i created to test the code: [Test Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8z78ssqhmknouq/test.zip?dl=0)

You could do this yourself in couple of steps:

1. Create an As3 project in the IDE of your choice. (I use FlashDevelop)
2. Declare the variable of type YourClass (Notas) which holds instance of your class
3. before using functions of your class make an instance of your class and store it in the variable.
4. viola, use public methods and properties of your class by accessing the variable you created.

this is the main function:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author tkiafar
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _not:Notas;
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) {
                _not = new Notas(this.stage);
                _not.asignarNotas();
                _not.Inicializar();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

this is your class that resides in the main package (beside main.as):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Notas
    {
        public var stage:Stage;
        public var velocidad:int = 5;

        public var i:int = 0;
        public var j:int = 0;
        public var notaS:Array = new Array(16);
        public var notaD:Array = new Array(16);

        public function Notas(escenario:Stage)
        {
            stage = escenario;
        }

        public function Inicializar():void
        {
            crearNotaS(0xFF00FF, 30, 10, 0, 0);
        }

        public function Destruir():void
        {
            if (notaS[i].y < 720)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < notaS.length; i++)
                {
                    stage.removeChild(notaS[i])
                }
            }
        }

        public function Mover():void
        {
            notaS[i].y += velocidad;
        }

        public function drawRect(color:uint, ancho:int, alto:int, x:int, y:int):Sprite
        {
            var dj:Sprite = new Sprite();

            dj.graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
            dj.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, ancho, alto);
            dj.graphics.endFill();

            dj.x = x;
            dj.y = y;

            return (dj);
        }

        public function asignarNotas():void
        {
            notaS[0] = 1
        }

        public function crearNotaS(color:int, ancho:int, alto:int, x:int, y:int):void
        {
            var contador:int = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < notaS.length; i++)
            {
                if (notaS[i] == 1 && i == 0)
                {
                    notaS[i] = drawRect(color, ancho, alto, x, y);
                    stage.addChild(notaS[i]);
                    notaS[i].y = -alto / 2;
                }
                else if (notaS[i] == 1 && i > 0)
                {
                    for (j = i; j < notaS.length; j++)
                    {
                        contador = i - j

                        notaS[i] = drawRect(color, ancho, alto, x, notaS[j].y + alto * contador);
                        stage.addChild(notaS[i]);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

after all i have some suggestions:

- seperate the array that contains control indexes and the one that contains sprites.
- avoid making variables public. in your case there is no need for accessing them outside your class, but if you need to make them accessible, use getters/setters. google "getters/setters in as3".
- invent some naming standards of your own. google "rules of naming in as3".